# How to index a converted userdata value?

Tags: c++, lua, swig, lua-userdata, typemaps

I tried to convert C++ class to a void pointer using `lua_touserdata()` and then convert it back to C++ class using `lua_pushlightuserdata()`.

However, I can't index variables in a class once I do the conversion.

Here's my test code:

**`MyBindings.h`**

```
class Vec2
{
public:
    Vec2():x(0), y(0){};
    Vec2(float x, float y):x(x), y(y){};
    float x, y;
};

void *getPtr(void *p)
{
    return p;
}
```

**`MyBindings.i`**

```
%module my
%{
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%typemap(typecheck) void* 
{
    $1 = lua_isuserdata(L, $input);
}
%typemap(in) void* 
{
    $1 = lua_touserdata(L, $input);
}

%typemap(out) void* 
{
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, $1);
    ++SWIG_arg;
}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C"
{
    int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    const int ret = luaL_dostring(L, "local vec = my.Vec2(3, 4)\n"
                                     "local p = my.getPtr(vec)\n"
                                     "print(p.x)");
    if (ret)
    {
        std::cout << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
    }
    lua_close(L);
}
```

**The Result I get :**

> [string "local vec = my.Vec2(3, 4)..."]:3: attempt to index a userdata
>   value (local 'p')

**The Result I expect :**

> 3

What should I do to get the result I expect?

Comment: Why do you push `Vec2` as `void*`?  If you really want to push it as `void*` and still be able to index it, you need full userdata and metatables.  But why don't you just let SWIG do the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it like this you have to adapt you design.  First of all the function `getPtr` cannot work because it is too generic.  There is no way SWIG will magically guess the type and do the right thing.  You will have to at least fix the type of the input.

**`MyBindings.h`**

```cpp
struct Vec2 {
    Vec2() : x(0), y(0){};
    Vec2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y){};
    float x, y;
};

void *getPtr(Vec2 &p) { return &p; }
```

Again, are you really sure you want to do this?  Because it is going to get ugly!

You need at least two metamethods, `__index` and `__newindex`, to get and set elements of the vector through the pointer.  I implemented these in the literal block (`%{ ... %}`) of the interface file but you can also move them to a header and include this header in the literal block.

Now you have to let Lua know about the metamethods you defined and insert them in a named metatable, so that you can distinguish pointers of type `Vec2` from other pointers.  Therefore you have to put a bit in the `%init` section of the interface file to register the metatable when the interpreter starts up.

Because you had to get rid of the `void*` input argument to `getPtr`, the `typecheck` and `in` typemaps can be removed.  The `out` typemap has to be adapted.  We have to allocate memory for a userdata which fits a pointer to `Vec2`.  We set the userdata to this pointer and slap the `Vec2` metatable onto it.  Now that was super easy wasn't it?<sub>(sarcasm)</sub>

**`MyBindings.i`**

```cpp
%module my
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include <string>
    #include "MyBindings.h"

    static int setVec2(lua_State *L) {
        Vec2 *v = *static_cast<Vec2 **>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Vec2"));
        luaL_argcheck(L, v != nullptr, 1, "invalid pointer");
        std::string index = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
        luaL_argcheck(L, index == "x" || index == "y", 2, "index out of range");
        luaL_argcheck(L, lua_isnumber(L, 3), 3, "not a number");
        float record = lua_tonumber(L, 3);

        if (index == "x") {
            v->x = record;
        } else if (index == "y") {
            v->y = record;
        } else {
            assert(false); // Can't happen!
        }

        return 0;
    }

    static int getVec2(lua_State *L) {
        Vec2 *v = *static_cast<Vec2 **>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Vec2"));
        luaL_argcheck(L, v != nullptr, 1, "invalid pointer");
        std::string index = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
        luaL_argcheck(L, index == "x" || index == "y", 2, "index out of range");

        if (index == "x") {
            lua_pushnumber(L, v->x);
        } else if (index == "y") {
            lua_pushnumber(L, v->y);
        } else {
            assert(false); // Can't happen!
        }

        return 1;
    }

    static const struct luaL_Reg Vec2_meta[] = {
        {"__newindex", setVec2},
        {"__index", getVec2},
        {nullptr, nullptr} // sentinel
    };
%}

%init %{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "Vec2");
    luaL_setfuncs(L, Vec2_meta, 0);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
%}

%typemap(out) void* 
{
    void * udata = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Vec2 *));
    *static_cast<void **>(udata) = $1;
    luaL_getmetatable(L, "Vec2");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    ++SWIG_arg;
}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

Let's see whether it works.

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local my = require("my")
local vec = my.Vec2(3, 4)
local p = my.getPtr(vec)
print(p.x, p.y)
p.x = 1.0
p.y = 2.0
print(p.x, p.y)
print(vec.x, vec.y)
```

```
$ swig -lua -c++ MyBindings.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I/usr/include/lua5.3 -fPIC -shared MyBindings_wrap.cxx -o my.so -llua5.3
$ lua5.3 test.lua
3.0 4.0
1.0 2.0
1.0 2.0
```

It might be a little easier if you used light userdata, but that has the downside that all light userdata will share the same metatable, so you can only do this for one kind of object.

---

#### Answer to the comment

Casting a pointer to a certain type to `void*` is called type erasure, because you lose all information about the data contained.  Therefore you have to be careful when restoring the type, that you actually restore the correct type.  Casting to an unrelated type is undefined behaviour and, if you are lucky, results in a program crash.

You probably don't want to be able to use `void*` like a `Vec2`.  What's the purpose of casting to `void*` then, when you want to retain the original meaning anyway.  Instead you want to have two functions, `getPtr` and `getVec2`.  The `getPtr` function erases the type and gives you a `void*` object which is unusable in Lua, but is handy to pass to callback functions which accept arbitrary data as `void*`.  The `getVec2` function restores the type to `Vec2` once you are done.

In the example the `getVec2` function returns by reference, i.e. the returned object will be a reference to the object you called `getPtr` on.  That also means that if the original object is garbage collected you have an invalid pointer, which will crash your application.

**`MyBindings.h`**

```cpp
struct Vec2 {
    Vec2() : x(0), y(0){};
    Vec2(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y){};
    float x, y;
};

void *getPtr(Vec2 &p) { return &p; }
Vec2 &getVec2(void *p) { return *static_cast<Vec2 *>(p); }
```

**`MyBindings.i`**

```cpp
%module my
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local my = require("my")
local vec = my.Vec2(3, 4)
-- Erase the type of vec to pass it around
local p = my.getPtr(vec)
-- Then restore the type using getVec2
local v = my.getVec2(p)
-- Take care! v is a reference to vec
v.x = 1.0
v.y = 2.0
print(v.x, v.y)
print(vec.x, vec.y)
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -lua -c++ MyBindings.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I/usr/include/lua5.3 -fPIC -shared MyBindings_wrap.cxx -o my.so -llua5.3
$ lua5.3 test.lua 
1.0 2.0
1.0 2.0
```

To see the reference semantics fail, place `vec = nil collectgarbage()` after `local p = my.getPtr(vec)`.  It doesn't crash on my machine but Valgrind reports invalid reads and writes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't expect the solution to be this complex. The reason I used `void *` argument was because I was looking for a universal solution that could apply to other classes. (e.g. `Vec3`).
 Do you mind adding an example using the light userdata?
All I want to do is be able to convert `userdata`(wrapped C++ class) to  a C++ pointer and then later convert the pointer back to the `userdata` so it can be used normally in Lua like it was. I will give you a bounty.

Comment: @ZackLee The complication arises from the fact that you want to access members through the pointer, so you somehow have to tag the userdata with the underlying type, which is achieved using the metatable.  If you only want to erase the type and later restore it, you can do it with light userdata and without a metatable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "if you only want to erase the type and later restore it". I would appreciate if you could add an example of this.

Comment: @ZackLee I mean that you only do `local p = getPtr(vec)` and later `local v = getVec2(p)` (this can be done with light userdata and without metatables).  It's only that complicated because you want `print(p.x)` to work.

Comment: Yes I think that would suffice as long as `print(v.x)` works in your example. I'd really appreciate if you can give me a hint on how to properly create `getPtr()` and `getVec2()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I will give you a bounty tomorrow. I'd appreciate if you could take a look at my other question which shows better what I want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242393/how-to-pass-userdata-from-one-lua-chunk-to-another-in-c
I will give you another bounty if you answer this one too.